# Uploading files to S3 through the server with multipart memory usage

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, nestjs, multipart

Working on a file uploading service, where the client uploads a file and the file goes through the server (for validations, and such) and uploads to S3 with multipart in chunks.

I use `multipart/form-data` upload, with [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) package.

**The reason I don't generate an upload link for S3 so the client will handle it is because I have a specific feature, where you take the upload progress client->server and server->s3 and calculate the upload percentage and notify other clients using the service, so the file must upload through the server.**

I'll try to break down what I've done with formidable to achieve a multipart upload to S3, I used NestJS as my server.

First of all the request handle:

```
@Post()
public async upload(@Req() req, @Res() res) {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    this.uploadProvider.uploadFile(req.sessionObject.id, 'test', form);
    form.parse(req, (fields, files) => {
        console.log(fields, files);
        res.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).json({});
    });
}
```

Which creates the form, and calls the `UploadProvider#uploadFile` method to start the process.

In that method, I override the `onPart` function of form:

```
    // Part is the first event that you receive since you override the onPart method in order to customize the upload process
    // To use S3 streaming
    form.onPart = (part) => {

        // Progress updating
        form.on('progress', (bytesReceived, bytesExpected) => {
        });

        // File uploaded to the API server
        form.on('end', () => {
        });


        // Stream parts to S3
        const upload = this.fileUploadFacade.getS3Stream().upload({
            Bucket: 'mytestbucket-files',
            Key: part.filename,
        });

        upload.concurrentParts(1);

        // Part sent to S3
        upload.on('part', (details) => {

        });

        // All parts streamed successfully to S3
        upload.on('uploaded', (details) => {

        });

        part.pipe(upload);
    }
```

****The issue****

The upload to S3 is working, but my major issue is the ram. I've tried uploading an 14gb file, and my nodejs process went up to 14gb memory usage.

I would like to ask if this is a general issue with file uploading, and if there are any alternative solutions for this

Thank you!

Comment: ever found a solution to this?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find a solution ?